# How to get the parent selection in d3?

Tags: d3.js

To create this DOM:

```
<g>
    <rect></rect>
    <circle></circle>
</g>
```

from `.enter()` selection, I tried:

```
someUpdate.enter()
  .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'my-group')
    .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'my-rect')
    // I'd like to get the .parent() here
    .append('cicle')
      .attr('class', 'my-circle')
```

This doesn't work since `.append('rect')` changes the selection to `rect`.

Breaking this to:

```
const update = someUpdate.enter()
  .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'my-group')

update
  .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'my-rect')

update
  .append('cicle')
    .attr('class', 'my-circle')
```

works.

But, I wonder if there is a cleaner way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no methods in D3 for traversing the DOM like e.g. jQuery's `.parent()`. Hence, the way you broke this down into separate statements will be the correct approach.

On the other hand, it is not completely impossible to do it the way you first suggested. Just yesterday I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41723198/4235784) to [*"D3.js - what is selection.call() returning?"*](/q/41721841) explaining how [`selection.call()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_call) will return exactly the selection it was called upon to allow for method chaining. Keeping that in mind you could something like the following:

```js
d3.select("svg").selectAll("g")
  .data([1])
  .enter().append('g')
    .call((parent) => parent.append('rect')
                        .attr("fill", "red")
                        .attr("width", 100).attr("height", 100))
    .call((parent) => parent.append('circle')
                        .attr("fill", "blue").attr("r", 50));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Both functions invoked by `.call()` will be passed the same selection of previously entered `<g>` elements, which happens to be the parent element in this case.

Although it *is* possible to do it this way, the solution has its drawbacks. First, it will look somewhat strange and awkward to any seasoned D3 developer, which might complicate matters if you want to share or discuss your code with others. Second, even though I named the parameter `parent`, which it is in this particular case, it is still not really an equivalent to jQuery's `.parent()` method. It will just pass in and return the very same selection be it a parent selection or something else.

Comment: My solution is stranger than yours.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with the others that your second code snippet is the correct way to do what you want **but** I want to play to, how about:

```js
d3.select("svg").selectAll("g")
    .data([1])
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .each(function() {
        var p = d3.select(this);
        p.append('rect')
          .attr("fill", "red")
          .attr("width", 100).attr("height", 100);
        p.append('circle')
            .attr("fill", "blue").attr("r", 50);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: As it is now, you are appending to the `<svg>` ifself; you need to use `d3.select(this)`, because `this` already refers to the parent group.

Comment: Your approach also was the first, which came to my mind, but I discarded it, because I think it just moves the problem to the function provided to `.each()`. You obtain a reference to the parent element and consecutively call `.append()` for each element to be appended. Whereas yours is called `p`, OP has it as `update`, which is not much of a difference. I think the *real* issue is more about method chaining rather than getting a hold of the parent element. And the *real* answer is, that, although it can be done, you will most likely be better off doing it the standard way.

Comment: @altocumulus, I completely agree.

Answer (score 2):

@altocumulus said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41760973/5768908):

> Although it is possible to do it this way, the solution has its drawbacks. First, it will look somewhat strange and awkward to any seasoned D3 developer.

Well, just as him, I have to say that OP's original code (appending the rectangle and the circle to the group separately) is the standard way, applied by the majority of D3 coders.

But, just for fun and to participate in this strange competition, here is another way to do it, using the less famous *third argument*:

```js
d3.select("svg").selectAll("g")
    .data([1])
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr("foo", function(d, i, p) {
        d3.select(p[0]).append('rect')
            .attr("fill", "red")
            .attr("width", 100).attr("height", 100);
        return null;
    })
    .attr("foo", function(d, i, p) {
        d3.select(p[0]).append('circle')
            .attr("fill", "blue").attr("r", 50);
        return null;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

I bet that this wins the "awkward code" competition.

Comment: If your functions returned `null` after appending the element, this would not even put a `foo` attribute on the `<g>`.

Comment: @altocumulus there you go.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, couldn't you just use `.each` instead of `.attr`?

Comment: @Mark `.each` is too adequate for the task... my objective here was going to be as awkward as possible.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, love it.

Comment: @Mark Thanks. That's why I used the third argument with the [0] index. `p[0]` is way more uncommon than a mere `this`...